# Getting a 1004 error when attempting to set a cell to a formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that has VBA code in it. Every time I run the script I am using I get a Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

I have identified that the following code is the issue, and it appears to specifically have an issue with "copying" the formula to the cell.

VBA Code:

```
If ActiveCell.HasFormula = True Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(ActiveCell.AddressLocal) = ActiveCell.Formula
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).AddressLocal) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula
End If
```

Formula in cell:

```
=HLOOKUP($G2,'https://mywebsite.com/[2023 Schedule.xlsm?NoRedirect=true]Schedule'!$Q$200:$NR$202,3,0)
```

Can someone tell me if there is an issue with this code/formula.

Thanks in advance!

**Update: I was able to determine that the issue is caused from the ?NoRedirect=true in the url for the workbook. Anyone able to suggest a reason that VBA does not like this?**

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use `.Address` instead of `.AddressLocal`?

Comment: Yes I do unfortunately 

Comment: What about `ActiveCell.Resize(,2).Copy`, `Sheets("Sheet1").Range(ActiveCell.Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas`?

Comment: Using `ActiveCell.Resize(,2).Copy` and `Sheets("Sheet1").Range(ActiveCell.Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas` gives a Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range

Comment: That means the active workbook has no sheet named "Sheet1"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Sheets("Sheet1")` use `Sheets(1)` - or whatever number sheet you are trying to access.

I get an error with your formula because the web link doesn't exist so also check that you have the name of the look up table correct.

Finally - avoid the use of Active... (Cell, Sheet, Workbook) - it is far too easy for that to be changed from what you think is actually active.

Comment: I was able to actually determine that the error is caused from the ?NoRedirect=true argument, not sure why but removing the ? from the requested workbook url fixes the issue.